# mongodb - get top items from a collection based on its usage count as a field in another collection

Tags: mongodb

How to get a list of top ranked items based on their usage as a field in items of another collection?

Here is a mongodb playground explaining the scenario - https://mongoplayground.net/p/gTMm1JVv9uV

In the example below, `category 245` is used twice and `276` is used once in the `posts` collection. The output will rank the categories based on their count of usage in `posts`

Note that the post collection only has the category id so looking up categories collection is necessary.

Based on this, the expected output is an array of category's text.

```
{
  topCategories: ["category 245", "category 276"]
}
```

A sample data in the two collections is below:

```
db={
  categories: [
    {
      "_id": 231,
      "text": "category 231",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": 245,
      "text": "category 245",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": 276,
      "text": "category 276",
      
    }
  ],
  posts: [
    {
      "_id": 71,
      category: "245"
    },
    {
      "_id": 72,
      category: "276"
    },
    {
      "_id": 74,
      category: "245"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `addToSet` in earlier query but found out that it does not maintain the order. I have replaced it with `push` operator.

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      category: {
        $toInt: "$category"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      as: "category",
      localField: "category",
      foreignField: "_id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$category"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$category._id",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "category": {
        "$first": "$category"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "count": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      categoriesText: "$category.text"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "categoriesText": {
        "$push": "$categoriesText"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      topCategories: "$categoriesText"
    }
  }
])
```

[New Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NPnWT-wBI4j)

Comment: Works 75% but is there a way to order them by number of occurences? In this case `category 245` should be listed first in the resulting array because it is used more times in posts. Thanks much

Comment: Ohh sorry missed that point. Actually I wrote the query yesterday. But when I came back to submit the answer you had already deleted the question.

Comment: Sorry that was a different question to get category text and it was not working because my database was storing ids as string and I was comparing with integer. I deleted it because it was my mistake that made it not work. This is more of a ranking question.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Sorry for if there is bad editing. I have done it on phone. Now the query shows text by rank.

Comment: It does not sort by rank still but no problem. Please update whenever you are on a computer even if it takes a day or two at your convenience. I will play with it and update if I solve it. Thanks much

Comment: I have updated the answer. Also realised that @turivishal has posted an answer too. But just wanted to be clear here i have not copied his answer. Honestly when i submitted my update and the page got refreshed, then i realised that there is another answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

- `$group` by `category` and convert to integer using `$toInt`, get count of total duplicate categories in count using `$sum`
- `$loopup` with categories collection
- `$sort` by count field descending order
- `$group` by null for combine categories in a array field, get first element from category array using `$arrayElemAt` and push it in `topCategories` field

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $toInt: "$category" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      as: "category",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id"
    }
  },
  { $sort: { count: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      topCategories: {
        $push: { $arrayElemAt: ["$category.text", 0] }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_rjZo8aak6b)